# Still having the version 2.7 after install the version 3.6 of python

Tags: apt, python

After installed python 3.6  from the the edwinksl's answer ([How do I install Python 3.6 using apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get)), I tried to test out the version of python on my computer with `pip --version` where I got the answer

```
pip 9.0.1 from /home/jeremie/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

and with sudo pip --version, I got pip 9.0.1 from /home/jeremie/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

I would like to uninstall canopy, and when I will execute one of the previous commands, I will like it displays the version 3.6. Could anyone have an idea how I could do such thing

```
┌─╼ [~]
└────╼ which pip3
/home/jeremie/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/pip3
┌─╼ [~]
└────╼ sudo which pip3
[sudo] password for jeremie: 
/usr/local/bin/pip3
┌─╼ [~]
└────╼ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/jeremie/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
┌─╼ [~]
└────╼ sudo pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/jeremie/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

**P.S.** In fact, I need python3 for using the brand new version of IPython (Ipython6)

Thanks!

Comment: [Edit] your post and include the output of `which python3` and `pip3 --version`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Python 2 in 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761106/how-to-remove-python-2-in-16-04)

Comment: I have modified my question for you @CarlH

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/451504/can-python-2-be-safely-removed-from-ubuntu-14-04 - why remove it? Also read https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3 and especially this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/244378/running-python-file-in-terminal

Comment: As far I I understand you're trying to install a bleeding edge release of IPython for Python3. Is `pip3 install ipython` not enough?

Answer (score 1):

As far I understand you're trying to install a bleeding edge release of IPython for Python3. Here's how you can do it:

```
pip3 install ipython
```

In fact, you wouldn't even need a newer Python release for that since the minimum Python version [required for IPython 6.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipython/6.0.0) is 3.3 (or 3.4 with Numpy). All currently supported Ubuntu releases provide at least Python 3.4 via the `python3` command.